# Unable to receive data from Socket using python in Linux

Tags: jquery, python, websocket, postman

So i have designed a simple data sending program using python on linux,but when i try to receive the data from $.get in jquery,Postman,it makes a connection and prints that a connection has been established,but i'm not able to get any data from it

Here's my Python code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket

s=socket.socket()
host='127.0.0.1'
port=8080

s.bind((host,port))

s.listen(5)

while True:
    print 'here'
    c, addr=s.accept()
    print 'Got connection from ', addr
    c.send('Thank you for connecting')
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can read data with `recv`

Comment: The receiving end i need it to be on HTML,and for some reason i'm not able to do that

Comment: In that case , it might be something with the client , still try reading the client's request first

Comment: You say you have a sending program in python and a receiving program in jquery... but you've posted a receiving program written in python and even though it does an `accept`, it doesn't call `recv`. So, um, what is that program and how does it relate to your problem?

Comment: I'm a noob over here @tdelaney,so this what i need to do,i want to send some data over the ip/port i have mentioned above,now i'm using an jquery to make a request to receive the data that i being sent and populate it onto the html

Comment: @t.m.adam now i'm confused with the client and server thing,hope what i've written clarifies

Comment: I mean  try `c.recv(1024)` first , and then `c.send('Thank you for connecting')`

Comment: but,i dont need c.recv,i just need to send the data and the recv part has to be done by javascript,which for some reason is not happening @t.m.adam

Comment: Can you include the js part ?